# Best technique to build a dynamic select

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have several filter fields in a form that will build the where expression of a select statement that will populate a `GridView`. The user also can choose the operators ( > < >= <= like) for each field . I would like to know the best technique to accomplish this task considering the pros and cons.

I got to some conclusions:

- Linq: not flexible to work with several possibilities and several operators.
- Stored Procedure: Make several parameters in a proc and in the where clause make `(table.description = isnull(@description, table.description)` but this does not allow us to work with several operators.
- use the `exec('Statement')` in a Proc. This way we can build the query dynamically but the query is full of quotes, which is boring to debug and modify, not sure about the performance.
- Dynamic Statements in the code, but this way we miss the procedure performance.

How an expert usually do? What is the best approach?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You could try to make an dynamic line expresion, i can't check atm how i did that, but if i get home and the question is not answered yet ill check that for you. that made mine dynamic results possible

Comment: The dynamic SQL approach is very common.  I have also done this with LINQ using PredicateBuilder.  http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: This question is a specific (and also very common) programming problem which is able to be solved using a precise software algorithm. I see no reason to suspend it.

Comment: i solved it the same way @Moby Disk suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last statement is incorrect. You could dinamically build your query in a string, either using native or EntityCommand if you use Entity Framework; there's no evidence that it would be less performatic than using stored procedures, unless you test it.

I've been using the following approach:

- Run through the filter expressions
- For each filter expression, add a filter to your WHERE clause (you are building an SQL string)
- For each filter expression, if needed, add a parameter information to a list (your are building a dictionary `<ParameterName, ParameterValue>`)
- After processing all filter expressions, build your query from your SQL string and add the parameters from your dictionary.